# foreach loop through array in JSON is null

Tags: c#, arrays, json, loops, foreach

I have an RESTclient and sending a response to a server. The response is a JSON.
I am able to display all information in the console, but in this JSON, there is an array.
To display the json im using a foreach loop, but i dont get the array in it. The Array object is null.

```
public class Test1
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Test2
    {
        public IList<Test> test{ get; set; }
    }


var test = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Test1>>().Result;
           

                foreach (var b in test)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", b.Name);
                }
            }
```

So I explain: The Test1 class is the information of the array. I get all informaiton from the JSON with test2.
But i want just the array with the "name" in it.
I think the foreach loop is alright and the problem is with the var "test".

I hope you understood and someone can help me :/

Thank you

Comment: Do you have the JSON response as a string? or like an output from the endpoint?

Comment: its like an output from the server

Comment: you should likely await the async read. to make sure it is done by the time you traverse the result.

second - do a null check to verify that test is not null.

Comment: and how can i await the async read?

Answer (score 1):

In case your JSON response is in the correct format then the response is most likely being processed in the for loop before it was actually received as you are reading it asynchronously.

You will need to await the response by adding the *await* keyword before your *ReadAsAsync* call and also add the *async* keyword to the method declaration.

```
public async void OutputResponse()
{
    var test = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Test1>>();
    foreach (var b in test)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("{0}", b.Name);
       }
}
```

Comment: and how can i use this in my Main method? :)

Comment: I don't know the system's architecture, but you have a couple of options.
If you have the OutputResponse method in the same class as your Main method then you can make the OutputResponse method static then you will be able to call it from within your Main method. You could also put the method in its own class. Then you would instantiate a new instance of this class within your Main method and call the OutputResponse method from the instantiated class object. Keep in mind that the Main method is only intended to be an entry point into the app, not to call everything from or house all the code.

Comment: i get the error, that the "GetAwaiter" has no definition

Comment: I think I know what the issue is and I will fix my answer. You need to remove the ".Result" from the following line. var test = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Test1>>().Result;

The Result property is not async, but the ReadAsAsync is async.

Could you possibly update your question to indicate where the "response" object comes from / is created?

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hey Ruan, i saw, that it is not working fine as i thought :(
I dont get into the array

Comment: @HIHI Could you possibly update your original question's code snippet to include the declaration or type of the "response" object? I'm assuming that it's of type HttpResponseMessage, but I think it would make the question more clear if it was included in the code snippet of the original question.